Where does Neovim's Lua List type come from?
Edit
This question was very misguided - the feature I'm referring to is from vimscript, not Lua.
Original question
In Neovim's Lua, in addition to normal table objects, you can create List objects like so:
x = [1, 2, 3]

The documentation for lists is fairly straightforward. However, it doesn't seem like 'standard' Lua supports any such syntax, to wit, my Lua 5.4.6 REPL yields an error:
> x = [1, 2, 3]
stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '['

NB, Neovim ships with Lua 5.1, with LuaJIT additionally available on common platforms.
Neovim also loads many utility functions by default in addition to the Lua standard library. This seems straightforward enough to me.
My question then is, if Neovim ships with 'vanilla' Lua/LuaJIT and only adds additional modules/functions, where does this special syntax come from? Or, if there are standard ways of implementing special syntax like this, where can I find the documentation for how to do so?

The content you referred to isn't Lua code; it's actually a Vim script. You can find at the top of the URL you provided: https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_41.html#41.8

       VIM USER MANUAL - by Bram Moolenaar
                Write a Vim script



Thank you! I'm still a little confused though. If this is vim script, why can I use it as-is in a Lua file? I think I goofed slightly in posting the question - obviously the doc I linked to is for vimscript. However, this syntax does work in Neovim's Lua, so the question still stands

@wurli An MRE would probably help. It doesn't work in my neovim lua files. Are you sure it wasn't wrapped in vim.cmd [[ ]] or something? Or maybe you're using a neovim distribution that's doing some magic under the hood?

@wurli the syntax doesn't work in my neovim could you send me what version of neovim you using
this is mine
`
NVIM v0.9.5
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1692716794
system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
fall-back for $VIM: "/__w/neovim/neovim/build/nvim.AppDir/usr/share/nvim"
Run :checkhealth for more info
`

Hi both - it looks like you're completely right, this is just a vimscript thing and doesn't work in Lua as I thought. I was sure I tested this, but apparently not, or perhaps I was within a vim.cmd [[ ]] block as suggested and didn't realise at the time. Thanks for the responses and bearing with the clearly very confused question!
